Showing an animated progress wheel in Jetpack Compose
In this Google Codelab (Mars Photos), while Coil is loading images, the app displays a progress wheel. The code uses this XML file as a drawable:

and uses this code to display it:
@Composable
fun LoadingScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.loading_img),
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.loading)
        )
    }
}

However, that only displays a static image. I want it to rotate (which I certainly expected as behavior). I've thought of some approaches, none of which I like much:

Define 12 similar XML files, one for each degree of rotation, and continually display each in sequence
Dynamically generate the XML and somehow convert it into a painter on the fly
Use Coil to load a GIF

Is there a simpler way of accomplishing this task? Is there a way to rotate the image itself programmatically such as applying a predefined animation mode of some sort (perhaps similar to basicMarquee)?

Here's the code for the same. This code is taken from https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-ProgressIndicator and it has many other spinning circular progress view animations.
@Composable
fun SpinningProgressIndicator(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @androidx.annotation.IntRange(from = 4, to = 12) staticItemCount: Int = 12,
    dynamicItemCount: Int = staticItemCount / 2,
    staticItemColor: Color = StaticItemColor,
    dynamicItemColor: Color = DynamicItemColor,
    spinnerShape: SpinnerShape = SpinnerShape.RoundedRect,
    durationMillis: Int = 1000
) {

    // Number of rotating items
    val animatedItemCount = dynamicItemCount.coerceIn(1, staticItemCount)

    val coefficient = 360f / staticItemCount

    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val angle by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = staticItemCount.toFloat(),
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = durationMillis,
                easing = LinearEasing
            ),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        )
    )

    Canvas(modifier = modifier
        .progressSemantics()
        .size(Size)
    ) {

        var canvasWidth = size.width
        var canvasHeight = size.height

        if (canvasHeight < canvasWidth) {
            canvasWidth = canvasHeight
        } else {
            canvasHeight = canvasWidth
        }

        val itemWidth = canvasWidth * .3f
        val itemHeight = canvasHeight / staticItemCount

        val cornerRadius = itemWidth.coerceAtMost(itemHeight) / 2

        val horizontalOffset = (size.width - size.height).coerceAtLeast(0f) / 2
        val verticalOffset = (size.height - size.width).coerceAtLeast(0f) / 2

        val topLeftOffset = Offset(
            x = horizontalOffset + canvasWidth - itemWidth,
            y = verticalOffset + (canvasHeight - itemHeight) / 2
        )

        val size = Size(itemWidth, itemHeight)

        // Stationary items
        for (i in 0..360 step 360 / staticItemCount) {
            rotate(i.toFloat()) {
                    drawRect(
                        color = staticItemColor,
                        topLeft = topLeftOffset,
                        size = size,
                    )
            }
        }

        // Dynamic items
        for (i in 0..animatedItemCount) {
            // angle is cast to into move in intervals of static items
            rotate((angle.toInt() + i) * coefficient) {
                    drawRect(
                        color = dynamicItemColor.copy(
                            alpha = (0.2f + 0.15f * i).coerceIn(
                                0f, 1f
                            )
                        ),
                        topLeft = topLeftOffset,
                        size = size,
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}

val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition() is used for infinite transition animation and RepeatMode.Restart means the animation restarts giving a feel of infinite animation.
rotate((angle.toInt() + i) * coefficient) { where you rotate the items. All the angle caluclations are in radians.
You can customize this to your needs. You don't need a image. Draw lines or rect and then animate few of them by rotating it.

Very useful indeed. Thank you.
